# C++ how to extract the first and rest of a string?

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I have a piece of string "`abcd`" I would like a function to get char '`a`' from "`abcd`" and another function to get "`bcd`" from "`abcd`".

Comment: are you talking about std::string, or just "strings" in a general sense?

Comment: @Tim In C++, std::string is the "general sense".

Comment: @Neil - Well - to those that know c++ sure - but if a person has to ask this question I will not assume that much...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using an `std::string`, you want:

```
str[0] // for the first char
str.substr(1) // for the rest of string
```

If you're using standard C `char*` strings, you want:

```
str[0] // for the first char

((char*)str+1) // or
&str[1]        // for the rest of string
```

When using the former method, ensure you're catching `out_of_range` exceptions, or are checking for string length in prior to calling it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited: I realize I was giving a C++.NET example before.**

What you're looking for is the `substr` method. If you have a string `s` containing "abcd", performing `s.substr(0,1)` will give you a string containing "a" and `s.substr(1,3)` will give you a string containing "bcd".

Comment: std::string doesn't have  substring method - that is C#. And who is voting this stuff up?

Comment: why are there still downvotes for this?  It has been corrected.

Comment: @Tim: downvotes don't automatically go away when the answer is "corrected."

Comment: @Seth - I understand that - but users should update the downvotes... though I suppose not all users check back.  I had figures the ones who were downvoting were the other active participants and he changed/fixed it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
TCHAR s[] = _T("abcd");

// Get 'a'
TCHAR c = s[0];

// Get "bcd"
TCHAR *p = s + 1;
```

Comment: FYI, `TCHAR` is not part of ANSI / ISO C or C++.  Although the OP didn't specify the string format.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't see where I said it was. You vote me down because of the flavor of code I present?

Comment: I did not vote you down.  All I'm saying is that `TCHAR` is not ANSI C or C++.  In general, when an OP doesn't present platform information, the objective is to supply an answer that is ANSI compliant.  The `TCHAR` is a Microsoft invention.